# Assign result of executing text/template template into a variable

Tags: go, go-templates

```
type Inventory struct {
    Material string
    Count    uint
}

sweaters := Inventory{"wool", 17}
tmpl, err := template.New("test").Parse("{{.Count}} items are made of {{.Material}}")
err = tmpl.Execute(os.Stdout, sweaters)
```

Instead of writing to `os.Stdout`, how can I save the result of the template execution in a golang variable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

as you may see here https://golang.org/pkg/text/template/#Template.Execute, there is an `io.Writer` arg in the execute method, so you may pass any `io.Writer`

i hope this will help. https://play.golang.org/p/kXRQ7G3uO20

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "bytes"
    "text/template"
)

type Inventory struct {
    Material string
    Count    uint
}


func main() {
    var buf bytes.Buffer
    sweaters := Inventory{"wool", 17}
    tmpl, _ := template.New("test").Parse("{{.Count}} items are made of {{.Material}}")
    _ = tmpl.Execute(&buf, sweaters)
    
    s := buf.String()
    fmt.Println(s)
}
```